# Is it OK to use lambda function parameter as a constant expression?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, static-assert, consteval

Why in [this example](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:4,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:4,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:4,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:4),source:%27consteval+auto+foo(auto+x)+%7B%0A++++static_assert(x)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%7B%0A++++foo(42)%3B+++//+error:+non-constant+condition+for+static+assertion%0A++++foo(%5B%5D%7B%7D)%3B+//+OK%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g122,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) the first call doesn't compile and the second one compiles?

```
consteval auto foo(auto x) {
    static_assert(x);
}

int main(){
    foo(42);   // error: non-constant condition for static assertion
    foo([]{}); // OK
}
```

If I understand correctly, the first one is wrong due to lvalue-to-rvalue conversion not being a constant expression. Why then the second one is OK?

Comment: No, function parameters like `x` are never constexpr.

Comment: @JasonLiam The question is why the second call works nonetheless.

Comment: @user17732522 Yes, that is why i didn't post an answer saying the same.

Comment: @JasonLiam it's like a practical conclusion which IIUC follows from [expr.const#5.9](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5.9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static_assert(x);` while passing `[]{}` works, because a capture-less lambda has a conversion operator to function pointer and a function pointer can be converted to a `bool` (which is going to be `true` for everything but a null pointer which the conversion can't return).

An expression is a core constant expression as long as it doesn't fall in any of a number of exceptions listed in [[expr.const]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#5). In relation to the potentially relevant exceptions, neither is `x` a reference, which would disqualify the expression `x` from being a constant expression immediately, nor is a lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on `x` or one of its subobjects required in the call to the conversion function or the conversion to `bool`. The returned function pointer is in no way dependent on the value of the lambda. The call to the conversion function is also allowed in a constant expression, since it is specified to be `constexpr` ([[expr.prim.lambda.closure]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.prim.lambda.closure#11)), so that the exception of calling a non-`constexpr` function also doesn't apply.

None of the exceptions apply and `x` (including the conversions to `bool`) is a constant expression. The same is not true if `42` is passed, because the conversion to `bool` includes an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on `x` itself.